# Decoding using a Huffman tree

Tags: c++, tree, huffman-code, inorder, postorder

The snippet below is not returning the correct text. The code takes in a pointer to the root node of a Huffman code tree and a binary text, which it then converts. However, every time it returns a single letter repeated.

```
string decode(Node *root, string code) {
    string d = ""; char c; Node *node = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < code.size(); i++) {
        node = (code[i] == 0) ? node->left_child : node->right_child;
        if ((c = node->value) < 128) {
            d += c;
            node = root;
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

The code for the Node object:

```
class Node {
public:
  Node(int i, Node *l = nullptr, Node *r = nullptr) {
      value = i;
      left_child = l;
      right_child = r;
  }
  int value;
  Node *left_child;
  Node *right_child;
};
```

The code for building the tree:

```
Node* buildTree(vector<int> in, vector<int> post, int in_left, int in_right, int *post_index) {
    Node *node = new Node(post[*post_index]);
    (*post_index)--;

    if (in_left == in_right) {
        return node;
    }

    int in_index;
    for (int i = in_left; i <= in_right; i++) {
        if (in[i] == node->value) {
            in_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    node->right_child = buildTree(in, post, in_index + 1, in_right, post_index);
    node->left_child = buildTree(in, post, in_left, in_index - 1, post_index);

    return node;
}
```

Example tree:

```
        130
       /   \
     129    65
    /   \
  66     128
        /   \
      76     77
```

Example I/O:
Input: `101010010111`
Output: `A�A�A��A�AAA`

The diamond characters are the numbers greater than 128.

Comment: You've written `code[i] == 0`, this assumes the string contains *actual zero-valued chars*, instead of `'0'`. Which is it?

Comment: Thank you for spotting that error, but still its not right. When I input the snippet "cout << node << endl;" after the if statement it outputs the same address code.size() times. I don't know if that will help.

Comment: Perhaps some internal nodes have a low `value`? Or bad child pointers? I'm just guessing here, it would be easy to confirm or rule out these problems in the debugger though

Comment: You need to show how you make the Node and an example code string we can run to debug this. As harold says it's probably your Node that's bad.

Comment: Okay, I just edited.

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow I've posted the Node code and the buildtree code. The tree is made from an inorder and a postorder traversal.

Comment: @harold Here I edited just in case.